# Manipulate Hash to typecast true/false for certain values

Tags: ruby

is there a better why how can I refactor this code, making sure that values in a `Hash` are typecasted to `true/false` if their value is `'1'` or `'0'` while leaving unaltered the rest?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 if that matters, and I'd like to improve this code.

```
  def transform
    hsh = {}
    preferences.each do |k, v|
      v = case v
      when '1'
        true
      when '0'
        false
      else
        v
      end
      hsh[k.to_sym] = v
    end
    hsh
  end
```

*updated with benchmarks*

All right, here's the performance test based on the replies so far:

```
class Test
  HSH = {"xxx"=>"xxx-rrr", "yyy"=>"0", "rrr"=>"1", "nnn"=>"0", "kkk"=>"1", "iii"=>"1", "lll"=>"default", "mmm"=>"76", "www"=>"1"}

  def self.transform_case
    hsh = {}
    HSH.each do |k, v|
      v = case v
      when '1'
        true
      when '0'
        false
      else
        v
      end
      hsh[k.to_sym] = v
    end
    hsh
  end

  def self.transform_ternary
    Hash[ HSH.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v == '1' ? true : v == '2' ? false : v ] } ]
  end

  def self.transform_fetch
    special_values = {"1" => true, "0" => false}
    Hash[HSH.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, special_values.fetch(v, v)] }]
  end

  def self.transform_negation
    Hash[ preferences.map {|k,v| [k.to_sym, !!v]} ]
  end
end

Benchmark.bm(20) do|b|

  b.report('case') do
    1500.times { Test.transform_case }
  end

  b.report('ternary') do
    1500.times { Test.transform_ternary }
  end

  b.report('fetch') do
    1500.times { Test.transform_fetch }
  end

  b.report('negation') do
    1500.times { Test.transform_negation }
  end
end

                           user     system      total        real
case                   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009282)
ternary                0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.013794)
fetch                  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.012804)
negation               0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.010760)
```

It appears that my original implementation is faster. Or is the BM test wrong?

Comment: don't select an answer so soon! leave time for others to answer.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks :) I'm going to do some benchmarks between the replies before selecting then. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @tokland that this kind of benchmark is not quite relevant : as your current code works, the question you asked was implicitly about expressiveness. And then : 1) your `HSH` should be a lot longer for your benchmark to be representative (possible differences in big'O) 2) in `transform_fetch` you create a `special_values` hash every time the method is called, which is not necessary and hurts performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code should be as declarative as possible (usually by using [functional style](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming)):

```
def transform
  special_values = {"1" => true, "0" => false}
  Hash[preferences.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, special_values.fetch(v, v)] }]
end
```

However, `Hash[...]` is very ugly and I prefer a more OOP approach with [Enumerable#mash](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#graph-instance_method), so I'd really write `preferences.mash { |k, v| [k.to_sym, special_values.fetch(v, v)] }`.

Comment: Added benchmarks to the original post

Comment: @John: A benchmark of this kind of code is not relevant. Go for the most declarative code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Hash[ preferences.map {|k,v| [k.to_sym, v.nonzero? or false]} ]
```

This preserves the value if it is nonzero, otherwise makes it false. It does not change a 1 to true though. I like @tokland's answer best, because it not only does the exact transformation you want, but makes it easy to extend and use as a general purpose transformer (if you ever need to change other values as well), which one might assume is your purpose for this method, based on the name.

**Code review**

Note that when you initialize a return variable and then loop over another variable, e.g.

```
hsh = {}
preferences.each do
  #something that updates hsh
end
```

A more idiomatic Ruby way to do this is with a `map`, as the answers show. This will in general result in more concise, expressive code.